# firebase get parent key by child value without child key

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have the following structure:

[image: Firebase Image]

how i can get all parent key where child value contain `4YCpSJIECJaMEp5poIGL4rIFnbs1`

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only search across level of child nodes. Since your JSON structure contains two unknown levels, you can't query for a value. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested

Answer (score 2):

You can't get only a parent key with Firebase's queries. If you get parent's key you'll retrieve childs too. What you can do is first query on your key filter and then do the rest on front side. Try the following:

```
firebase.database().ref("roomUsers").orderByValue().equalsTo(key).once("value").then(snap => {
   const keys = [];
   snap.forEach(s => {
      keys.push(s.key);
   });
});
```

Comment: What is equalsto(key)? Where is key defined?

Comment: `key` is the parent's key you want to retrieve.